# How can I push a new view when detail button is presses

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView. My tableView cells do have a detail accessory.
My question: How can I push another view controller when the detail button is presses.
When I normally press the cell, my ViewController1 opens. But when I tap on the little i on the right of the cell, I want to push a different view controller.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just like `DidSelectRow` u need to modify `DidSelectRow` to  `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // if u using .Xib
 yourviewcontrollerName *vie=[[yourviewcontrollerName alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: vie animated:YES];

   //// if u using storyboard

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yoursequeName"
                      sender:self];


}
```

you need more information use this link [Pushing to a Detail View from a Table View Cell using Xcode Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464164/pushing-to-a-detail-view-from-a-table-view-cell-using-xcode-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       // Push new View controller here
       UIViewController *objVc=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objVc animated:YES]

    }
```